# App name in launcher

Tags: android, label

There where some similar questions around here but my problem is a bit different. I use a label for an activity to be displayed and the system automatically uses that text as the app name which is seen under the app icon in the launcher. BUT I have already set the app name, as u can see in that manifest code:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".OneActivity"
        android:label="Project 51" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: not clear what your question is.

Comment: the question is: why is "Project 51" displayed in the system launcher (where u can find all apps) as the name of my application, though in string/app_name something else is defined? "Project 51" is actually the label for the OneActivity and not the app name

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it should work as intended (unless app_name in strings.xml is actually set to "Project 51"). All I can think of is give the intent-filter the label of the application and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm with AJcodez.  It looks fine as long as app_name is set correctly.  got to your strings.xml and check what that is set to.